# Create Root Object Upon Login with ASP.MVC & EF5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, simplemembership

What is the best way to initialize (create or load) a root level object upon login within an MVC4 application using the SimpleMembership provider?  A good example would be an "Inbox" object for a user.  When the user logs in for the first time their Inbox would be created and linked to their user account.  Upon subsequent logins the Inbox object would be loaded for that user so that all child objects (folders, messages, etc.) would be accessible under that object.  It is important that I not extend the provider or Account controller/model that ASP.NET provides.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to extend the provider or models I would call [WebSecurity.CurrentUserId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.currentuserid%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) after successful registration and logon of a new user.  This provides the unique database ID generated by the system which you could then use as a foreign key in another database/table to link to your Inbox object.  Thereafter any time they logon you would call CurrentUserId and do a query on Inbox with the ID to get the correct box.

The user profile in SimpleMembership is made to be easily customized as described in this [article](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html). If I understood the restrictions around modifying the existing account model I might be able to offer other solutions.